# Given some conditions finding the number of relation between two sets .

Tags: combinatorics, functions

[image]

This means that for each element in A there should be one unique image in B.But, this is the definition of a function. So, I selected option (A). But, the answer is given to be (D). Please help me understand my mistake.

Comment: If you tell us *why* did you choose (A) then it will be possible to help you understand *your* mistake. Otherwise the most we can do is explain the correct answer to you.

Comment: Because that is the result that I studied in school which gives the number of functions from A to B.

Comment: The condition only says that for each element $a \in A$ there is at most one $b \in B$ satisfying $R(a,b)$, but it doesn't say anything if there should be one in the first place. For example, an empty relation satisfies the given condition, but it would not be a function if $A \neq \varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that every such relation is a function, but it isn't a function from $A$ into $B$. Rather it is a function from a subset of $A$ into $B$, this is because we don't require that the domain of these $R$ is $A$ itself.

It is true that there are $n^m$ functions from $A$ to $B$, but partial functions there are more. To see why there are exactly $(n+1)^m$, add another element to $B$, and call it $*$. Now every relation in this collection you can extend to a function into $B\cup\{*\}$ by the following rule: $$R\mapsto R_*=R\cup\{(a,*)\mid a\notin\operatorname{dom}(R)\}$$

You can show that this rule is a bijection between your collection and the functions from $A$ into $B\cup\{*\}$. Therefore the collection has the size $(n+1)^m$.